# Java project runs in netbeans but not from command line

Tags: java, netbeans

I am a C# Developer, and I recently acquired a project at work that is Java.

The Project is to modify an existing Java application, which I have done and was simple. However, I can not for the life of me get it to run from the command line.

I am receiving the error

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
         at com.dhl.sop.label.LabelReportHandler.main(LabelReportHandler.java:63)
```

There is no code at line 63 in that file. I have altered the file dramatically just to see that line number change, and it hasn't. I am really not sure what else to do, I have googled a bit and I have come up empty handed. Any information and/or suggestions are greatly appreciated.

Thank you!
- Jeffrey

EDIT: Here is the source code

```
http://speedy.sh/5wdBq/SOPLabel.zip
```

EDIT: The command I am running

```
generateSOPLabel.cmd
```

EDIT: The command the cmd script is running

```
java com.dhl.sop.label.LabelReportHandler
```

Comment: Show us some code and let us know what you've tried on the command line?

Comment: Sounds like an Object is declared but not Instantiated. That is, there may be LabelReportHandler declared somewhere; but the program is expecting it to be Instantiated (LabelReportHandler lrh = new LabelReportHandler) or assigned one at least. With the limited information, that's my guess.

Comment: Just to make sure, can you enter the exact command you are typing into the command prompt?

Comment: Thank you so much fellas, I have edited my post and included the source code and the command I am executing

Comment: Any ideas or suggestions are greatly appreciated, I would love to get this working before the weekend, seems like its a really simple java rookie mistake

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, it's working just fine for me after fixing the ant build script to build the files and pointing the startscript to the correct output files.

Your problem is probably that Netbeans are building the files to the BUILD folder and the script is looking in CLASSES.

Changes in startscript:

```
export CLASSFILE_PATH=$SOPLabel/build/
 ..
java  -classpath $CLASSPATH com.dhl.sop.label.LabelReportHandler
```

Added to build.xml:

```
 <target name="compile" 
        description="compile the source ">    
    <javac srcdir="src" destdir="build"
             classpathref="classpath"/>   </target>
```

Built with: `ant compile` and then `enter code here`./generateSOPLabel.sh outputs:

> Usage : java LabelReportHandler
>
> where
>
> Request XML MessagePath : The complete path of the request XML message
>   to be send. E.g. .\RequestXML\shipval.xml
>
> Response PDF Path : The complete directory path where the respose XML
>   messages are to be saved. E.g. .\PDFReports\n